# Vector implementation copy constructor error

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to implement a version of vector (for learning purposes). My code fails to create second vector with copy constructor raising SIGABRT in insert() function. Still can't find my mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

**array.h**

```
#ifndef ARRAY
#define ARRAY
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

template <typename Object>
class Array
{
    private:
            int s;
            Object *array;
    public:
            Array()
            {
                this->array = NULL;
                this->s = 0;
            }

            ~Array()
            {
                this->clear();
            }

            Array (const Array <Object> &arr)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
                {
                    this->push_back (arr.array[i]);
                }
            }

            class const_iterator
            {
                protected:
                    Object *parent;

                public:
                    const_iterator()
                    {
                    }

                    const_iterator (Object *a)
                    {
                        this->parent = a;
                    }

                    const_iterator (const const_iterator &itr)
                    {
                        this->parent = itr.parent;
                    }

                    const Object operator*() const
                    {
                        if (this->parent)
                        {
                            return *(this->parent);
                        }
                        throw 0;
                    }

                    const_iterator &operator++()
                    {
                        if (this->parent && this->parent + 1)
                        {
                            ++this->parent;
                        }
                        return *this;
                    }

                    const_iterator operator++ (int)
                    {
                        const_iterator old = *this;
                        ++(*this);
                        return old;
                    }

                    const_iterator &operator--()
                    {
                        if (this->parent && this->parent - 1)
                        {
                            --this->parent;
                        }
                        return *this;
                    }

                    const_iterator operator-- (int)
                    {
                        const_iterator old = *this;
                        --(*this);
                        return old;
                    }

                    bool operator== (const const_iterator &rhs) const
                    {
                        return this->parent == rhs.parent;
                    }

                    bool operator!= (const const_iterator &rhs) const
                    {
                        return this->parent != rhs.parent;
                    }

                    const_iterator &operator= (const const_iterator &rhs)
                    {
                        this->parent = rhs.parent;
                        return *this;
                    }

                    friend class Array <Object>;

            };

            class iterator : public const_iterator
            {

                protected:
                    Object *parent;

                public:
                    iterator()
                    {
                    }

                    iterator (Object *a)
                    {
                        this->parent = a;
                    }

                    iterator (const iterator &itr)
                    {
                        this->parent = itr.parent;
                    }

                    const Object &operator*() const
                    {
                        if (this->parent)
                        {
                            const Object result = *this->parent;
                            return result;
                        }
                        throw 0;
                    }

                    Object &operator*()
                    {
                        if (this->parent)
                        {
                            return *this->parent;
                        }
                        throw 0;
                    }

                    iterator &operator++()
                    {
                        if (this->parent && this->parent + 1)
                        {
                            ++this->parent;
                        }
                        return *this;
                    }

                    iterator operator++ (int)
                    {
                        const_iterator old = *this;
                        ++(*this);
                        return old;
                    }

                    iterator &operator--()
                    {
                        if (this->parent && this->parent - 1)
                        {
                            --this->parent;
                        }
                        return *this;
                    }

                    iterator operator-- (int)
                    {
                        const_iterator old = *this;
                        --(*this);
                        return old;
                    }

                    bool operator== (const iterator &rhs) const
                    {
                        return this->parent == rhs.parent;
                    }

                    bool operator!= (const iterator &rhs) const
                    {
                        return this->parent != rhs.parent;
                    }

                    iterator &operator= (const iterator &rhs)
                    {
                        this->parent = rhs.parent;
                        return *this;
                    }

                    friend class Array <Object>;
            };

            iterator begin()
            {
                return iterator (this->array);
            }

            const_iterator begin() const
            {
                return const_iterator (this->array);
            }

            iterator end()
            {
                return iterator (this->array + this->s);
            }

            const_iterator end() const
            {
                return const_iterator (this->array + this->s);
            }

            int size() const
            {
                return this->s;
            }

            Object &front()
            {
                if (this->array)
                {
                    return *this->array;
                }
                throw 1;
            }

            const Object front() const
            {
                if (this->array)
                {
                    const Object result = *(this->array);
                    return result;
                }
            }

            Object &back()
            {
                if (this->array)
                {
                    return *(this->array + this->s - 1);
                }
            }

            const Object back() const
            {
                if (this->array)
                {
                    const Object result = *(this->array + this->s - 1);
                    return result;
                }
            }

            void push_back (Object &o)
            {
                if (this->s)
                    this->insert (iterator (this->array + this->s - 1), o);
                else
                    this->insert (iterator (this->array), o);
            }

            void pop_back()
            {
                if (this->array)
                {
                    this->erase (iterator (this->array + this->s - 1));
                }
            }

            iterator insert (iterator itr, Object &obj)
            {
                Object *destination = itr.parent;
                if (destination)
                {
                    ++this->s;
                    Object *newArray = new Object [this->s];
                    int i;
                    Object *temp = this->array;
                    for (i = 0; temp != destination; ++i, ++temp)
                    {
                        newArray[i] = *temp;
                    }
                    newArray[i] = *temp;
                    ++i;
                    ++temp;
                    newArray[i] = obj;
                    iterator result (newArray + i);
                    ++i;
                    while (i < this->s)
                    {
                        newArray[i] = *temp;
                        ++i;
                        ++temp;
                    }
                    delete [] this->array;
                    this->array = newArray;
                    return result;
                }
                else if (!this->s)
                {
                    ++this->s;
                    this->array = new Object;
                    *(this->array) = obj;
                    return iterator (this->array);
                }
                else
                {
                    return iterator (NULL);
                }
            }

            iterator erase (iterator itr, Object &obj)
            {
                Object *destination = itr.parent;
                if (destination)
                {
                    --this->s;
                    Object *newArray = new Object [this->s];
                    int i;
                    Object *temp = this->array;
                    for (i = 0; temp != destination; ++i, ++temp)
                    {
                        newArray[i] = *temp;
                    }
                    ++temp;
                    newArray[i] = *temp;
                    iterator result (newArray+i);
                    ++i;
                    ++temp;
                    while (i < this->s)
                    {
                        newArray[i] = *temp;
                        ++i;
                        ++temp;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return iterator (NULL);
                }
            }

            void clear()
            {
                if (this->array)
                {
                    delete [] this->array;
                    this->s = 0;
                }
            }

            bool operator== (const Array <Object> &rhs)
            {
                if (this->s != rhs.size())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this->s; ++i)
                    {
                        if (this->array[i] != rhs[i])
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }

            bool operator != (const Array <Object> &rhs)
            {
                if (this->s != rhs.size())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this->s; ++i)
                    {
                        if (this->array[i] != rhs[i])
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }

            Array &operator= (const Array <Object> &rhs)
            {
                if (this->size)
                {
                    delete [] this->array;
                    this->size = 0;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < rhs.size(); ++i)
                {
                    this->push_back (rhs.array[i]);
                }
                return *this;
            }

            Object &operator[] (const int index)
            {
                return this->array[index];
            }
};

#endif
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Array <int> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        test.push_back (i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << test[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    Array <int> test1 (test); /* fails here */
    for (int i = 0; i < test1.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << test1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You set, `this->array = NULL;` in your constructor and then You are simply dereferencing a `nullptr` in the copy constructor. This causes a UB resulting in a seg fault. `this` needs to point to some valid memory location.

Comment: It's okay to strip out the needless white space when posting.

Comment: If you really need to post a wall of code for us to debug for you, then at least don't spam it with millions of newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialize `array` and `s` in the copy constructor.